Refreshing captcha while posting data to website
Im trying to post data with webrequest(c#) to a website but main problem is;
When i try to post data mostly i get "captcha timeout " error , website has text-based captcha and valid for 60secs.
And i have to upload a photo to website and it took very long time (service unavailable error and i think its depend website servers)
So i need to refresh captcha before posting data.
Im using web request, how can i refresh captcha image before posting data.
Here is captcha generate and refresh funcion;
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {$('#60ee911e3d8b4ab2a81223b1b79dc2b8').show();})

function ______23d64ebdce98416d91616e7df791c674________() { $('#60ee911e3d8b4ab2a81223b1b79dc2b8').hide(); $.post("/Form/DefaultCaptcha/Refresh", { t: $('#CaptchaDeText').val(), __m__: "0" }, function(){$('#60ee911e3d8b4ab2a81223b1b79dc2b8').show();}); return false; }</script> 

<br/>

<img id="CaptchaImage" src="/Form/DefaultCaptcha/Generate?t=cc4e44a6a71d48b78b25039b6b161dd6"/><input id="CaptchaDeText" name="CaptchaDeText" type="hidden" value="cc4e44a6a71d48b78b25039b6b161dd6" /> <br/><a href="#CaptchaImage" id="60ee911e3d8b4ab2a81223b1b79dc2b8" onclick="______23d64ebdce98416d91616e7df791c674________()" style="display:none;">Refresh</a><br/>The answer is<br/><input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id="CaptchaInputText" name="CaptchaInputText" type="text" value="" />

and here is my code for getting captcha from website;
var result = await _httpClient.GetAsync("/Form");
if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    _prepeareTasks.Add(UploadImage());// it took more than 60secs         
    var html = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    _doc.LoadHtml(html);
    var deTestDom = _doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"CaptchaDeText\"]");
    if (deTestDom is not null)
        _deText = deTestDom.Attributes["value"].Value;
var result = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"Form/DefaultCaptcha/Generate?t={_deText}");

